# Line breaks reading input from XML

Tags: xml, powershell, octopus-deploy

I'm creating a script to install Octopus Tentacles in 2.6.5. To read the values that change I'm pulling them from an XML to go into a PowerShell script. I keep running into the issue where the `instanceName` is creating line breaks.

So for:

```
Write-Output "$homePath\$instanceName\$instanceName.config"
```

I am getting:

```
C:Apps\Octopus\Tentacle\

Test

\

Test.config
```

It's doing a line break where the `instanceName` is being used.

Here is my XML and PowerShell:

XML:

```
<OctopusEnviroment>
<Sxsport>
10933
</Sxsport>
<instanceName>
Test
</instanceName>
<sthumb>
3FD6D126A383A949262668B5D9E36F08A7699B748
</sthumb>
```

PowerShell:

```
$sxsportVar = ""
$instanceNameVar = ""
$sthumbVar = ""

[xml]$SiteAttribute = Get-Content OctopusEnv.xml


$sxsportVar = $SiteAttribute.OctopusEnviroment.Sxsport
$instanceNameVar = $SiteAttribute.OctopusEnviroment.instanceName
$sthumbVar = $SiteAttribute.OctopusEnviroment.sthumb

####Instance name the Tentacle will be registered to
$instanceName = $instanceNameVar
####Thumbprint from Deployment Server
$sthumb = $sthumbVar
####Port Tentacle is listening on
$sxsPort = $sxsportVar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a question here but you probably want to remove the line breaks?

```
$SiteAttribute.OctopusEnviroment.instanceName -replace '\s'
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.